# Selecting Multiple Rows in One Query with Multiple Conditions

Tags: mysql, select

I can select multiple rows with one condition by using something like:

```
SELECT `Col`, `Col2` FROM `Table` WHERE `Col3` IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
# This selects 5 rows
```

How can this be done if there are multiple conditions (all integer equals operations)?

There are three conditions that the query needs to check against and all three of these make up the composite primary key.

A single query will select from 10 to 100 rows (though most of the time it'll be only 10)- it has to be fast in terms of performance. This is why using multiple queries isn't a good idea.

The `CREATE TABLE` statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table Name` (
  `X` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Y` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Z` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Data` varchar(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`X`,`Y`,`Z`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With multiple queries, it could be done like this:

```
SELECT `One`, `Two` FROM `Table` WHERE `X` = ? AND `Y` = ? AND `Z` = ?;
SELECT `One`, `Two` FROM `Table` WHERE `X` = ? AND `Y` = ? AND `Z` = ?;
SELECT `One`, `Two` FROM `Table` WHERE `X` = ? AND `Y` = ? AND `Z` = ?;
# This selects 3 rows but I don't want to make 3 calls to the database server for that
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 2 basic syntactical options for doing this in one query and 2 options on whether to send the values in the query or load them first in a table:

- the normal `AND` / `OR` (parentheses are redundant here but it's good to use them with `OR`, just in case the `WHERE` gets more complicated):

  ```
  WHERE (  ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? )
        OR ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? )
        ... 
        OR ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? )
        )
  ```
- compact `IN` with "row constructor":

  ```
  WHERE (x,y,z) IN ((?,?,?), (?,?,?), ...)
  ```
- load the triplets in a (temporary) table and `JOIN`:

  ```
  CREATE (TEMPORARY) TABLE tmp_table 
  --- ;

  INSERT INTO tmp_table (x,y,z)
  VALUES (?,?,?), (?,?,?), ... ;

  SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table AS t
    JOIN tmp_table AS tmp
    ON  ( t.x = tmp.x AND t.y = tmp.y AND t.z = tmp.z )
   ;
  ```
- or:

  ```
    ON  (t.x, t.y, t.z) = (tmp.x, tmp.y, tmp.z)
  ```

The first 2 options are equivalent but they may differ in efficiency, depending on version. This syntax of `IN` with tuples (row constructors) does not use indexes most effectively in older versions. In 5.7 the optimizer identifies the two syntaxes as equivalent (see [MySQL docs: Row Constructor Expression Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html)). **Test!**

The other choice of using a table may be better when you want to query for a number of parameters / triplets. You can also index the (temp) table. **Test!**

So, the basic advice is to **test** in your version/configuration/setup, with the tables having sizes similar to their predicted sizes, and with various number of parameters.

---

Two more ways that might be worth testing too:

- The simple `UNION ALL`. Since we just want to run multiple identical queries where only the parameters differ. One disadvantage is that the query gets really long and clumsy-looking if the basic query is complex and you have many triplets to check:

  ```
  SELECT t.* FROM my_table AS t
  WHERE ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? ) UNION ALL
  SELECT t.* FROM my_table AS t
  WHERE ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? ) UNION ALL
  ---
  SELECT t.* FROM my_table AS t
  WHERE ( x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ? ) ;
  ```
- Using a derived table (with `UNION ALL`) in the `JOIN` variation. This may use an optimization (that was added in 5.5 or 5.6) that can materialize and index a derived table:

  ```
  SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table AS t
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT ? AS x, ? AS y, ? AS z  UNION ALL
          SELECT ?, ?, ?  UNION ALL
          ---
          SELECT ?, ?, ?
        )
      AS tmp
    ON  ( t.x = tmp.x AND t.y = tmp.y AND t.z = tmp.z )
   ;
  ```

Comment: Normal `AND`/`OR`: 1.0-1.2ms for 15 triplets/rows
Compact `IN`: 0.6-0.8ms for 15 triplets/rows

They both seem to have 35ms in the first query, which is really strange.
I'll test it with a temporary table tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: If the first execution is slower than the rest, then it's a cache effect, so the next executions are fast only because the data is already in memory or MySQL has cached the query result. You should use `SQL_NO_CACHE` or run multiple queries with randomized/different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A note for MariaDB.
Row Constructor Expression Optimization DOES NOT WORK! 
My version is 10.1.24 and I don't see it mentioned in the 10.2 notes either!
I did not test it for a PRIMARY but I did test for UNIQUE and normal INDEX.

Also, if you are using AND/OR and the query length is getting high (at aprox 1200 conditions - not an exact figure) then the query analyzer fails to pick the proper index so you need to add a FORCE INDEX clause in your QUERY.

Long queries - bad analyze. Row constructor would have saved the day.